# mybatis error org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime

Tags: java, mybatis

i use jdk 1.7.0_76-b13, mybatis 3.2.8, and i have some code as follow:

```
List<Long> ids = 

ids = ids.subList();

someDAO.getByIds(ids);
```

and in my mapper.xml i have test code:

```
<when test="ids != null and ids.size() > 0">
```

i get some error :

```
Class org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime can not access a member of class java.util.ArrayList$SubList with modifiers "public"]
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.OgnlCache.getValue(OgnlCache.java:47) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ExpressionEvaluator.evaluateBoolean(ExpressionEvaluator.java:32) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.IfSqlNode.apply(IfSqlNode.java:33) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ChooseSqlNode.apply(ChooseSqlNode.java:34) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:32) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicSqlSource.getBoundSql(DynamicSqlSource.java:40) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.getBoundSql(MappedStatement.java:278) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:118) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:108) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:102) ~[mybatis-3.2.8.jar:3.2.8]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor182.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:358) ~[mybatis-spring-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
```

can anybody tell me why?

Comment: if it is possible please debug your application at `org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.OgnlCache.getValue(OgnlCache.java:47)` and check what each local variables' value and publish it here, that should be useful.

Comment: post your full query and stacktrace so that it's easy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Using an OGNL earlier than 2.7 causes this problem with Mybatis 3.2.x. Either use a 3.3.x version of Mybatis or don't use the `anonymous_inner_classes` of Collection in order to avoid this bug.

Comment: It happens accidently on currency